# How to stop PHP file execution with exec or shell_exec

Tags: php, shell

I have triggered a PHP file which has an infinite loop, with:

```
shell_exec('php '.__DIR__.'/serv.php 2>&1 > /dev/null &');
```

and now I can't to stop it.

Is there any way to do it with '`shell_exec`' or '`exec`'?

Comment: instead of killing all php procceses just kill the one, if you have use htop, f3 > search > php > find it > f9 > kill it > with fire > 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a service. You can either run `killall php` or `killall php-cgi`in shell or, if you are using a program like MAMP or WAMP, you can simply close and reopen the program. Also, if you are using a later version of PHP there should be infinite loop failsafes. Check your php.ini for `max_execution_time` to see how long the script should be allowed to run. You can also set this in your file using the [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function.

Comment: Thanks, killed with 'killall php' ;)

Answer (score 0):

just run the following on your shell

```
killall php
```